# MvxPictureChooserTask OnPicture not called

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I did a simple mvvmcross application on android which should take a picture and display it on the screen to be saved later with other information. The problem is that when i call

```
_pictureChooserTask.TakePicture(400, 95, OnPicture, () => {});
```

the camera opens and i take the photo, but when i click the 'check' button to close the camera, the method OnPicture() is never called, so the camera activity remains on the screen. 
I did an implementation of this before with mvvmcross 3.5.1, now im using the latest 4.4.0 and this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using Xamarin.AndroidSupportv4 23.4.0.1 instead of the latest 24.2.1